# Word repetition in python 3 without using count or dictionary command

Tags: list, python-3.4

My assignment that I am struggling with is creating a program that can count word repetition in a poem and display it in a list using Python 3 without using a counter. So far, I've only been able to populate each word from the poem into a list and then populate another list with each of the words without repetition by using:

```
    data = open('Romeo.txt')

wordList = []
allWords = []
uniqueWords = []




for line in data:
    word = line.split()
    if word not in wordList:
        wordList.append(word)


for word in wordList:
    for sword in word:
        if sword not in allWords:
            allWords.append(sword)
```

Comment: You can accomplish what you have so far much faster by `add`ing to a `set`. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set .

Comment: To confirm, you want some sort of (word, count) *without* any use of dictionaries or the `count` command? Intuitively a dictionary would seem to be the way to go, but without one, your program will be dramatically slower. One way to do this is to store a set/list of lists [word, count] unique for each word (and we create [word, 1] if the word was not found) and you will modify its count as necessary.

Comment: I don't understand what your intended storage method is. I cover lots of ways to do this in this blog post, but all of them involve dictionaries (hopefully looking through these methods will help?): http://treyhunner.com/2015/11/counting-things-in-python/